# Flink window state size and state management

Tags: apache-flink, stream-processing

After reading flink's documentation and searching around, i couldn't entirely understand how flink's handles state in its  windows.
Lets say i have an hourly tumbling window with an aggregation function that accumulate msgs into some java pojo or scala case class. 
Will The size of that window be tied to the number of events entering that window in a single hour, or will it just be tied to the pojo/case class, as im accumalting the events into that object. (e.g if counting 10000 msgs into an integer, will the size be close to 10000 * msg size or size of an int?)
Also, if im using pojos or case classes, does flink handle the state for me (spills to disk if memory exhausted/saves state at check points etc) or must i use flink's state objects for that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The state size of a window depends on the type of function that you apply. If you apply a `ReduceFunction` or `AggregateFunction`, arriving data is immediately aggregated and the window only holds the aggregated value. If you apply a `ProcessWindowFunction` or `WindowFunction`, Flink collects all input records and applies the function when time (event or processing time depending on the window type) passes the window's end time.

You can also combine both types of functions, i.e., have an `AggregateFunction` followed by a `ProcessWindowFunction`. In that case, arriving records are immediately aggregated and when the window is closed, the aggregation result is passed as single value to the `ProcessWindowFunction`. This is useful because you have incremental aggregation (due to `ReduceFunction` / `AggregateFunction`) but also access to the window metadata like begin and end timestamp (due to `ProcessWindowFunction`).

How the state is managed depends on the chosen state backend. If you configure the `FsStateBackend` all local state is kept on the heap of the TaskManager and the JVM process is killed with an `OutOfMemoryError` if the state grows too large. If you configure the `RocksDBStateBackend` state is spilled to disk. This comes with de/serialization costs for every state access but gives much more storage for state.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! So, even if i choose file system backend i will get oom for state too large? I thought it only happens for heap state backend.

Comment: Yes, OOM may be occur with `FsStateBackend`. See here [Flink official doc.](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/ops/state/state_backends.html#the-memorystatebackend) @yaarix

Comment: The name of `FsStateBackend` is confusing IMO. The `Fs` (Filesystem) part refers to the location where the checkpoints are stored, not how the local state is stored that the function works with. For `RocksDBStateBackend` this is the other way round. RocksDB is the local state store and the checkpoints are also stored in a (distributed) filesystem.

Comment: @FabianHueske this is a very helpful insight. Just to confirm, so if I am using SQL/Table API, then I could safely assume that the window functions are all aggregateFunction? As with sql (group by)query, I do not see we can apply the `ProcessingWindowFunction` as you mentioned above.